# MySQL C# connector - make it not use IPv6

Tags: c#, mysql

I am attempting to connect to a mySQL server using the mySQL C#/Connector and am getting the following error:

Host 'fe80::bd5a:7eea:8157:199%11' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Looking at my IPConfig I see that it is:

Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::bd5a:7eea:8157:199%11

so my question(s) are:

- a) How do I make the MySqlConnection class use IPv4
- b) Specify a source host name

Supporting info:

Web.config:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="mysqlConn" connectionString="server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;User Id=xxx;password=xxx;Persist Security Info=True;database=xxx" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: in the connectionstring, you are using an IPv4 IP, right? Is it 127.0.0.1? Are you able to allow the user to connect from that IPv6 address?

Comment: Yes I am using an IPv4 address. I am unable to change the mySQL server settings to allow any IPv6 changes (and don't want to connect via v6)

Comment: If you don't want anything else to use IPv6 either, then I guess disabling IPv6 on the network adapter would work, although it's not a great solution. You could at least verify that you can connect when IPv6 is disabled that way. :\

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue with "machine name" cannot connect to this database. As a temporary fix I went into the database setup and allowed all entry points (i.e. all IP Addresses) with a wildcard '%'.

Again, this is only a temporary fix. If you want a bit more security try specifying the IPv4 address directly.